# use a literal for type in assignment

Tags: go

I'm using the code in `func Root` as a guide to create another method `Login` shown below. In particular, in `Root`, I assign the literal `Book{}` to `b` and then use the result in the `Scan`.  That code doesn't throw any errors (although I'm not sure if it's nice code), but when I try to do something similar in the `Login` function, which I'm modifying from this [blogpost](http://shadynasty.biz/blog/2012/09/05/auth-and-sessions/), I get this error

```
cannot use User literal (type User) as type *User in assignment
```

for what it's worth, I also get this error right above when I compile

```
no new variables on left side of :=
```

but aren't I doing the same thing in the second method, namely assigning the literal `u := User{}` to a variable and then using it in the scan?

Can you explain using the code below when you can and can't use a literal for type in an assignment?

```
func Root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT title, author, description FROM books")
    books := []Book{}
    for rows.Next() {
        b := Book{}
        err := rows.Scan(&b.Title, &b.Author, &b.Description)
        PanicIf(err)
        books = append(books, b)
    }
    ...//code ommitted



func Login(password, email string) (u *User, err error) {
    u := User{}
    db.QueryRow("select * from users where email=$1 ", email).Scan(&u.Id, &u.Password, &u.Email)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    err = bcrypt.CompareHashAndPassword(u.Password, []byte(password))
    if err != nil {
        u = nil
    }
    return
}
```

Comment: i am also facing same error, but looking at your example it is not clear to me which line number you are getting error. hope your example could help me, but it doesnt seem to.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simplifying your example to focus on the essentials:

```
package main

import "net/http"

type Book struct{}

type User struct{}

func Root(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    books := []Book{}
    _ = books
}

func Login(password, email string) (u *User, err error) {
    // no new variables on left side of :=
    // cannot use User literal (type User) as type *User in assignment
    // u := User{}
    u = &User{}
    return
}

func main() {}
```

The function declaration for `Login` declares a result parameter `u *User`, a pointer to type `User`.

The `u := User{}` statement is a short variable declaration of type `User`.

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Short variable
>   declarations](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations)
>
> A short variable declaration uses the syntax:
>
> ShortVarDecl = IdentifierList ":=" ExpressionList .
>
> It is shorthand for a regular variable declaration with initializer
>   expressions but no types:
>
> "var" IdentifierList = ExpressionList .
>
> Unlike regular variable declarations, a short variable declaration may
>   redeclare variables provided they were originally declared earlier in
>   the same block with the same type, and at least one of the non-blank
>   variables is new. As a consequence, redeclaration can only appear in a
>   multi-variable short declaration. Redeclaration does not introduce a
>   new variable; it just assigns a new value to the original.

Since the variable `u` has already been declared in the same block (`u *User`), the compiler complains that `u := User{}` has "`no new variables on left side of :=`." Write `u = User{}` for a simple assignment.

The statement `books := []Book{}` is a short variable declaration for a new variable, `book`, in the block.

The declaration `u *User` says that `u` is a pointer to a variable of type `User`.

> [The Go Programming Language
>   Specification](http://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Composite literals](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals)
>
> Composite literals construct values for structs, arrays, slices, and
>   maps and create a new value each time they are evaluated. They consist
>   of the type of the value followed by a brace-bound list of composite
>   elements. An element may be a single expression or a key-value pair.
>
> The LiteralType must be a struct, array, slice, or map type (the
>   grammar enforces this constraint except when the type is given as a
>   TypeName). The types of the expressions must be assignable to the
>   respective field, element, and key types of the LiteralType; there is
>   no additional conversion.
>
> Taking the address of a composite literal generates a pointer to a
>   unique instance of the literal's value.

The composite literal `User{}` is a literal value of type `User`, not `*User`. The compiler complains that "`cannot use User literal (type User) as type *User in assignment`." Take the address of the composite literal for a pointer to a literal value of type `User` (`*User`). Write `u = &User{}`.

Answer (score 2):

- `b := Book{}` defines a new variable (`b` wasn't defined before), so it can take the value type `Book`
- `u := User{}` doesn't define a new variable, because it was part of the method return parameter `u *User`, so you can't use `:=`.
  It would be `u=&User{}`.

`u` here is a [named result parameter](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#named-results):

> if the function executes a return statement with no arguments, the current values of the result parameters are used as the returned values.